# Matlab constructor of superclass after return statement

Tags: matlab, return, subclass, superclass

I am trying to check if a parameter is of a certain type when instantiating a subclass of a superclass, and I keep getting an error that appears to be associated with my method of checking of the argument type. The debugger won't even let me include a breakpoint without throwing the error `A constructor call to superclass appears after the object is used, or after a return.` I think it's pretty obvious what line of code breaks my classes, but why am I not allowed to do this type checking? What other ways are there to confirm that my arguments are of a particular type? Code below.

```
classdef superClass < handle
      properties
          PropertyOne
          PropertyTwo
      end    
      methods
          function sup = superClass(param1, param2)
              sup.PropertyOne = param1;
              sup.PropertyTwo = param2;
          end
      end
end
classdef subClass < superClass
      properties
          PropertyThree
      end   
      methods
          function sub = subClass(param1, param2, param3)
              if ~isa(param1, 'char')
                  disp('param1 must be type char')
                  return
              end
              sub@superClass(param1, param2);
              sub.PropertyThree = param3;        
          end
      end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `subClass` like this:

```
classdef subClass < superClass
      properties
          PropertyThree
      end   
      methods
          function sub = subClass(param1, param2, param3)
              assert(ischar(param1),'param1 must be type char')
              sub@superClass(param1, param2);
              sub.PropertyThree = param3;        
          end
      end
end
```

You can't have the `return` statement before the superclass constructor runs. `return` would need to exit the function with an output for `sub`, and `sub` doesn't exist before the superclass constructor runs. If you use `assert` (or you could use `if` together with `error` instead, but `assert` is simpler), then it will exit with no output for `sub`, so it's OK.

Also note that you don't need `isa(..., 'char')`, you can just use `ischar`.